# IMAP email IDLE stops waiting timeout duration, instead loops instantaneously in Python

Tags: python, imap, gmail-imap, email-client

I have a program to check for new emails in an inbox using IMAP IDLE. Whenever I run it, it works perfectly at first. But after some time, it stops pausing for the IDLE timeout time and instead rapidly loops through the first part.

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

while True:
    try:
        #this is the part that's getting looped every half second when it breaks
        telegram('try portion starting again')

        # Wait for up to 540 seconds for an IDLE response
        responses = server.idle_check(timeout=540)
        if responses:
            telegram('Email Recieved')

            for response in responses:

                if response[0] not in checked_uids:

                    checked_uids.append(response[0])

                    uid = str(response[0])

                    with MailBox(HOST).login(USERNAME, PASSWORD) as mailbox:
                        for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(uid=uid)):

                            body_text=msg.text

                            telegram(body_text)
```

Where telegram() sends a telegram message to me.

So when this is working correctly, I get a message containing the body of a new email, and every 540 seconds I get a message that the try: portion has started again.

In my testing, it works just like this for some time then all of a sudden, for no reason I can discern, I get the "try portion starting again" message twice a second repeated to infinity. Meaning, seemingly the `responses = server.idle_check(timeout=540)` portion stops working as intended

edit: here is the catch section of the code I'm using. Super simple. I'm also not getting any error messages while the program is going crazy and cycling so quickly

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    telegram(e)
```

Comment: Where's the catch?  Do you print out the catch? potentially your connection got closed and it's continuously throwing exceptions, so it won't wait

Comment: Are you sure that idle_check returns the ids?

Comment: To answer Max's question, I've edited the original post. To answer Vladimir's question, I know that idle_check returns the ids (at least at first) because it works as intended. Meaning when I send an email to the address I'm streaming, I get the telegram(body_text) of the right email. UNTIL it breaks and starts looping instantly

Comment: Definitely take out the final blanket `except` to see more clearly where it's raising an error. Of course it's looping because you told it to.

Comment: tripleee- well shouldn't I get a message whenever there's an exception? That's the point of the telegram(e) line. I've tested intentionally causing errors and I do get messages when that happens, though I never get errors it starts looping instantly. As for why it's looping, I do want it to loop so that's not the part that bothers me. The part that's the problem is that it loops *instantaneously* and without waiting for the proper timeout time in the idle line

Comment: Still, debugging it when you are somehow hiding or losing the error is pretty much impossible, so that's what I would suggest. You can perhaps figure out a way to put it back once you understand what the problem is. My guess is that you will want to have many smaller and narrower exception handlers around the individual things which can fail instead of one whopping "big bang" handler which causes this looping symptom and generally only allows hamfisted and clunky error handling.

Comment: triplee- I can change it, but I don't see how that will help. When the program goes wrong currently, there aren't any exceptions. Later on I plan to add more specific error handling, but I haven't been able to see any errors to catch, because when the program goes wrong it doesn't raise any exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this. I still don't know why this happened in the first place, but this solved it for me.

I put `server.idle()` just within the `try:` code. Then I put `server.idle_done()` in a `finally` code segment. That way, every time the program loops it starts the idle and every time it ends it stops the idling. It seems like doing that every time makes the program more stable.

Answer (score 1):

since 0.51.0 imap_tools has IDLE support:

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/releases/tag/v0.51.0